# How to run actions on raw image (like florabella, MCP etc)

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing

I started exploring PS actions recently. Like florabella actions. Though I figured it out to run on JPEG, I could not figure it out to use it for RAW. RAW always opens in camera raw and I did not see any option there to load actions.

Is it possible to use actions on RAW or is it only to edit jpeg. please help. I use PS CS6.

Comment: Are you open to additional software?  Lightroom supports some automation options and can then open the image in Photoshop, but I'm not sure if there is a way to automate Camera Raw or not since it is a separate program that simply integrates with Photoshop to provide a raster image.

Comment: Is it possible to open a raw image in photoshop without using camera raw? Then how do most of those actions available on net run?? Like paint the moon, florabella,MCP etc?? First edit the RAW image in camera raw, convert to jpeg and then run actions?? But doesn't that degrage the image and cause loss of details?? Please help.

Comment: Does it support working on RAW files?  I couldn't find anything on their site that seemed to indicate RAW support.  Photoshop works on raster images, RAW is not an image, so something has to convert it to an image.  That's the job of either Lightroom or Camera Raw.

Comment: @PRK: don't convert to JPEG for sure! :-) Use anything lossless with embedded color profile, preferably high color-depth (16 bit or 32 bit). See [this link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/creativesuite/cs/using/WS91C1E0BD-9600-42b2-8EBE-1E012ED61058.html#WS43B6DFCC-DBBE-4a9a-A985-7871DF914288). "You can save camera raw files from the Camera Raw dialog box in PSD, TIFF, JPEG, or DNG format. " So you can save to PSD directly! (Or even DNG, and if you have installed a DNG import component, you can import that as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open a raw file in Photoshop it must go through ACR first. ACR basically converts the raw image into something photoshop understands. If you don't want to have to mess with the adjustments you could just leave everything at default or download a basic preset, and just let ACR pass the image over to PS.

Comment: Thanks I was looking for this answer... I finally figured out "open image" button in ACR opens the RAW file in photoshop. Then I can proceed with running actions.... (it was simple but took me time to figure out !!!)